# Do I really need to configure my server with a public static IP address?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

I'm setting a few sites up and many email accounts for a new company so I wanted to save some money as I already have a server running Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have a static IP of 80.229.46.115 and the server's IP is configured as 192.168.1.63. The server is at a business address and is using business broadband. Upon asking 123-reg.co.uk to add an A record for my FQA they have informed me I should not be using 192.168.1.63 under IPv4 settings manually and I should be using the actual static IP of 80.229.46.115.

When I try to add 80.229.46.115 under IPv4 it loses connectivity and under the machine's IP of 192.168.1.63 I am seeing the DNS server is running OK.

Is what the rep at 123-reg told me incorrect?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the rep is correct. 192.168.0.0/16 is a private IP range, and isn't available to the public Internet.

What you will need to do is use your public IP in the DNS record and then port-forward to one of your private IP addresses.

My personal advice, though, is to NOT use home Internet/networking for business use. What happens when your home broadband service or phone line goes down? Is your customer happy with having their data hosted on a residential premesis? How good is your home security (as well as your home network security)?

Comment: Hi sorry I didn't mention this is at a business address and is using business broadband. I am currently looking into some hardware based firewalls, any suggestions? - The title should have been first business server, doh! - PS: I'm not going to be using this for anybody elses businesses but my own until I fully understand the server inside out.

Comment: Also, how do I port forward the public IP 80.229.46.115  to the private IP of the machine within  Windows server 2008?

Comment: You'll need to use NAT (or more specifically Destination NAT or DNAT) to forward the specific ports you require via your router/firewall. Your device's documentation will help you with the exact steps.

Comment: Do I need to use two network cards for this, one for LAN and one for WAN as I've just installed Routing and Remote access on the Server but when I go through the steps of configuring and enabling NAT the 'use public interface to connect to the internet' is not allowing the radio button but 'create a new demand dial interface to the internet' is. Thanks for all the help thus far it's much appreciated!

Comment: I did not have to use NAT in the end I could port forward using DMZ in my router 'Technicolor TG582N' - Simply had to open port 80 for applications and then enable the server to bypass the firewall and NAT of the gateway.