# Do I need 2 NIC cards to forward public IP to private IP?

Tags: nat, nic

To use NAT do I need 2 nic cards? I want to use my server for my own business (I don't require VPN) and simply need to forward my public IP to the private IP so that websites show up as www.upnorthsound.co.uk and not the private IP of the machine.

I'm new to this and thank you in advance for your patience towards newbies like myself!

Regards, Jay.

Comment: Hi, you may be getting slightly confused here as NAT/PAT is typically done on the router (you can do it on a server however). The router will have 2 or more interfaces - one connects to the internet side, the other to your local network.

Comment: First see the answer to [your previous question](http://serverfault.com/questions/507069/do-i-really-need-to-configure-my-server-with-a-public-static-ip-address).

Answer (score 3):

How many NICs you need depends on the structure and number of networks which you want to be connected to. That's independent of NAT. You don't need an additional NIC for NAT, not even for routing.

It's generally not useful to ask something like that without any information about the configuration. [Have a look at the FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq) so that you can improve this and future questions.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need 2 nic's.
But you do need a router to do the NAT and to separate your LAN from the internet.

You are obviously not familiar enough with the concepts.
That makes putting your server onto the Wild-West of the Internet very risky.

The best advice I can give is that you get a professional to look at your situation and advice on the best (security wise) approach for your business.